# Can epoll or kqueue handle asynchronous additions of file descriptors to itself

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, epoll, kqueue

If one thread (say X) is waiting on an `epoll_wait()` can another thread (say Y) makes a call to `epoll_ctl()` to register interest in file descriptor `9`. Can the previous call to `epoll_wait()` in thread X return the file descriptor `9` added by thread Y? The initial call to `epoll_wait()` never returned in the middle at any point.

Now I want to compare this and ask related questions with respect to two other polling calls in operating systems. `poll()` and `kqueue`

1. If the answer to the above question is true then is there a way to achieve similar behavior with the `poll()` system call?
2. Let us assume that `epoll_ctl()` is thread safe and thread X can safely call `epoll_ctl()` and have the call to `epoll_wait()` return whether the file descriptor `9` is ready for I/O. The separation of the function to declare interest in the file descriptor and the function to wait is what would make this function amazing. But people often refer the `kqueue` and `epoll` as being used for the same functionality. However `kqueue` does not have a separate function to declare interest in getting event feedback for a descriptor. Does anybody know how `kqueue` can be used in a similar manner as `epoll`? `epoll` seems to be the best threadsafe option out there right now if it allows threadsafe "interest declaration"

Comment: With `kqueue` you may *declare interest* without *getting event feedback* by passing 0 as `nevents` parameter. See, e.g., [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756402/how-do-i-replace-select-with-kevent-for-higher-performance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [man epoll_wait](http://linux.die.net/man/2/epoll_wait):

> While one thread is blocked in a call to epoll_pwait(), it is possible for another thread to add a file descriptor to the waited-upon epoll instance. If the new file descriptor becomes ready, it will cause the epoll_wait() call to unblock.

So `epoll_wait` watches for a file descriptor added while it is waiting.

Such behavior cannot be achived by poll()/select(), as they read the set of file descriptors *once*, so one cannot modify the set of file descriptors which are currently polled.

[Of course, if you pass a file descriptor created by `epoll_create` to `poll()/select()`, modifications of this file descriptor will be tracked as with `epoll_wait`.]

Comment: I was not aware of there being an `epoll_pwait`.. What is the difference between `epoll_wait()` and `epoll_pwait()`?

Comment: Hm, it looks like a misprint in the man page: in the same sentence it uses `epoll_pwait` and `epoll_wait` while actually means the same function. `epoll_pwait` differs from `epoll_wait` in that it additionally allows given signal set during execution. See man for more details.

Comment: `epoll_pwait` isn't a misprint, it's a variant of `epoll_wait` that allows management for safe signal handling. Read more information [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/epoll_pwait).

Comment: @Myst: I am aware about existence of `epoll_pwait`. Misprint is using this function along with `epoll_wait` in the quoted note: `while one thread is blocked in ... *epoll_pwait*, ... it will cause the *epoll_wait* to unblock`. With different functions this note has no sence.